# Como faço esta inserção no banco de dados através do formulário?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá,

Não estou conseguindo fazer a conexão com o banco de dados.
O seguinte erro está aparecendo:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function msqli_query()
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\Clientes\dadosClientes.php:15 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Clientes\dadosClientes.php on line 15

O código PHP é o seguinte:

```php
<?php
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bd_cadastroclientes");

$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : "";
$tel = isset($_POST['tel']) ? $_POST['tel'] : "";
$endereco = isset($_POST['endereco']) ? $_POST['endereco'] : "";
$cidade = isset($_POST['cidade']) ? $_POST['cidade'] : "";

//inserindo registros
$sql = "INSERT INTO tb_clientes (nome, telefone, endereco, cidade) VALUES ('$nome', '$tel', '$endereco', '$cidade')";

$salvar = msqli_query($conexao, $sql);  (<<< Aqui está o erro)

header("Location:dadosClientes.php");
```

E o HTML é este:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cadastro de Clientes</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos/estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Cadastro de Cliente</h1>

            <form method="post" action="dadosClientes.php">

                Nome Completo: <input type="text" name="nome" required autofocus /><br/><br/>
                Telefone:      <input type="text" name="tel" required><br/><br/>
                Endereço:      <input type="text" name="endereco" required><br/><br/>
                Cidade:        <input type="text" name="cidade" required><br/><br/>

                <input type="submit" name="enviar">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Muito Obrigado! (obs: parece bem simples, porém não estou conseguindo. Iniciante kk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notei agora, está escrito errado

`msqli_query()` é `mysqli_query()`

Answer (score 1):

olá, está escrito de maneira errada query, tente assim:

```
 $salvar = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
```

outra coisa legal de se fazer e criar uma pagina apenas para conexão, e quando vc precisar dela so a adiciona e não precisa digitar toda vez. Ficaria assim:

### conexao.php

```
<?php

$hostname = "localhost"; //se você estiver usando servidor local
$user = "root"; // usuario root
$password = ""; // meu banco nao possui senha, então fica em branco
$database = "NOME_SEU_BANCO"; //adiciona o banco de dados 
$conexao = mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$password,$database);

if (!$conexao){
    print "falha na conexao com o BD";
}

?>
```

e quando você precisar adicionar ela em outra pagina usar o comando **include_once**

ex na sua pagina ficaria assim:

```
<?php

include_once("conexao.php");//usaria apenas essa linha, ao inves de digitar tudo com está em baixo 

        $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bd_cadastroclientes");

        $nome = isset($_POST['nome'])?($_POST['nome']):"";
        $tel = isset($_POST['tel'])?($_POST['tel']):"";
        $endereco = isset($_POST['endereco'])?($_POST['endereco']):"";
        $cidade = isset($_POST['cidade'])?($_POST['cidade']):"";

        //inserindo registros

        $sql = "insert into tb_clientes (nome,telefone,endereco,cidade) values ('$nome','$tel','$endereco','$cidade')";




        $salvar = msqli_query($conexao,$sql);  (<<< Aqui está o erro)

        header("Location:dadosClientes.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente o `mysqli` está desativado no seu `php.ini`.

Vá na pasta de instalação do php e procure o arquivo `php.ini`.

Edite o arquivo no bloco de notas e procure por

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Se estiver comentado (com um `;` na frente), como:

```
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Retire o ponto e vírgula do inicio:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Comment: Já está sem o ;

Answer (score 0):

olá fiz um codigo aqui que talvez lhe ajude

### inicio.html

```html
<div>
<h1>Cadastro de Cliente</h1>
<form method="post" action="dadosClientes.php">
    Nome Completo: <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu Nome:" required autofocus /><br/><br/>
    Telefone: <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="Digite seu telefone:" required><br/><br/>
    Endereço: <input type="text" name="endereco" placeholder="Digite seu endereço:" required><br/><br/>
    Cidade: <input type="text" name="cidade" placeholder="Digite sua cidade:" required><br/><br/>



    <input type="submit" name="enviar">
</form>
</div>
```

### conexao.php

```
<?php

$hostname = "localhost"; //se você estiver usando servidor local
$user = "root"; // usuario root
$password = ""; // meu banco nao possui senha, então fica em branco
$database = "bd_cadastroclientes"; //adiciona o banco de dados 
$conexao = mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$password,$database);

if (!$conexao){
    print "falha na conexao com o BD";
}

?>
```

### dadosClientes.php

```
<?php

include_once("conexao.php");



$nome =$_POST['nome'];
$tel =$_POST['tel'];
$endereco =$_POST['endereco'];
$cidade =$_POST['cidade'];


$sql = "insert into tb_clientes (nome,telefone,endereco,cidade) values ('$nome','$tel','$endereco','$cidade')";

$salvar = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

$linhas = mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);

mysqli_close($conexao);
}
?>

 <body>
<section>
 <?php

if($linhas == 1){
print"<h3>Sucesso! Formulario Enviado: <h3> <br>
<h5>Preenchido por: $nome - <br>
Telefone: $telefone -  <br>
endr :$endereco -  Em: $cidade - <br>

</h5>

<a href= inicio.php > <img src=  > </a>


                   ";

               }else{
                   print"<h2>Erro!<h2><h5>Consulte um Administrador:</h5>



                   <a href= inicio.php > <img src= > </a>

                   ";



               }

           header("Location:inicio.html");

               ?>


</section>

</body>
```